# Counting the total number of instances of some collection of objects in a list

Tags: list-manipulation, counting

I have a list of some sort `list = {"l1","l2","l3","l4"}` and I'd like to count the sum total number of occurrences of `n` of the elements in the list.  This is easily done for one element: `Count[list, "l1"]` which gives `1`.  How can I write something like `Count[list, "l3" OR "l2" OR "l1"]`, in this example giving the output `3`?  I read through the manual for `Count` and surprisingly couldn't find out how to ask for this.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 2) Read the [faq]! 3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [Alternatives](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Alternatives.html). You aren't getting any help from the `Count[]` docs because it's more related to [Patterns](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/guide/Patterns.html)

```
list = {"l1", "l2", "l3", "l4"};
Count[list, Alternatives["l1", "l2", "l3"]]
(* or abbreviated *)
Count[list, "l1" | "l2" | "l3"]
(*
 3
 3
*)
```

Answer (score 1):

Alternately,

```
Total@((#[[1]][#[[2]]] &) /@ Tuples[{##}]) &[(Function[v, 
Function[u, Length@Select[u, # == v &]]] /@ {"11", "12", 
"13"}), {{"11", "12", "13", "14"}}]
```

Comment: This gives the right result for the test case, but isn't it a bit convoluted compared with the built-in `Alternatives` function?

Comment: Yes, very much.